# How to sort value-of in xslt?

Tags: xslt

I wanted to sort some values in a xsl but my code doesn't work at all :(

```
<xsl:value-of select="Parameter[@Name='ID']/@Value"/>
```

So I want to sort the values of the parameter "ID".

My Code:

```
 <xsl:sort select="Parameter[@Name='ID']/@Value"/>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a minimal XML document that is the input, the expected output, the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the source XML as:

```
<main>
  <Parameter Name="ID"  Value="4">X1</Parameter>
  <Parameter Name="ID"  Value="3">X2</Parameter>
  <Parameter Name="xxx" Value="2">X3</Parameter>
  <Parameter Name="ID"  Value="1">X4</Parameter>
  <Parameter Name="ID"  Value="5">X5</Parameter>
</main>
```

(actually, you should have provided it).

The idea is to create a variable, I called it *par*, with:

- *xsl:perform-sort* selecting source nodes, and
- *xsl:sort* inside, providing the required sort.

For demonstration purpose, my script generates both original and sorted sequence
of *Value* attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="main">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="par">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="Parameter[@Name='ID']">
           <xsl:sort select="@Value"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
      </xsl:variable>
      <Sorted>
        <xsl:value-of select="$par/*/@Value"/>
      </Sorted>
      <Original>
        <xsl:value-of select="Parameter[@Name='ID']/@Value"/>
      </Original>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
   <Sorted>1 3 4 5</Sorted>
   <Original>4 3 1 5</Original>
</main>
```

Comment: To simply sort the sequence of `Value` attributes I would note that XSLT/XPath 3 allows that using the XPath `sort` function with e.g. `sort(Parameter[@Name='ID']/@Value)`, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifqs.

Comment: For your XSLT 2 use of  a variable and perform-sort, it would be easier and more efficient to type the variable e.g. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifqs/1 uses `<xsl:variable name="sorted-values" as="attribute()*">` to obtain a sorted sequence of the original attribute nodes while your current variable is a document fragment containing in the sorted order some copies of the original `Parameter` elements .